# Supremum and infimum of $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{a_k}{a_{k}+a_{k+1}+a_{k+2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let, $n\ge 3$ be a fixed integer. Take all the possible finite sequences $(a_1,a_2,..,a_n)$ of positive numbers. Find, supremum and infimum of 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{a_k}{a_{k}+a_{k+1}+a_{k+2}}$$
where, $a_{n+1}=a_1,a_{n+2}=a_2$

My partial progress:
Let, $s=a_1+a_2+..+a_n.$
Since, $$\frac{a_k}{s}\le\frac{a_k}{a_k+a_{k+1}+a_{k+2}}\le 1-\frac{a_k}{s}-\frac{a_{k+1}}{s}$$
which gives, $$1\le\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{a_k}{a_k+a_{k+1}+a_{k+2}}\le n-2$$
I guess, $n-2$ and $1$ will be the supremum and infinmum respectively,but I failed to show that.

Comment: What is $s$ in what you wrote?

Comment: Also, your sum should stop at $n-2$ in the statement.

Comment: I edited it.See now.

Comment: The fact that the sequence is "cyclic" ($a_{n+1}=a_1$) changes a *lot* of things.

Comment: See also:
[Supremum and infimum of a set of numbers $\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{a_k}{a_k+a_{k+1}+a_{k+2}}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/639097),
[$\inf$ and $\sup$ of a set given by $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{a_{k}}{a_{k}+a_{k+1}+a_{k+2}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/611874)

Answer (score -1):

Put $a_k=m^k$, when $m\rightarrow \infty $ the sum approaches $1$.

Put $a_k=m^{-k}$, when $m\rightarrow \infty $ the sum approaches $n-2$.